# How to run sonar analysis when Sonar server is configured over HTTPS

Tags: https, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We have a SonarQube server which is by default running on HTTP and 9000 port. We decided to use SonarQube over HTTPS configured using IIS reverse proxy and disable HTTP.

Previously in sonar-scanner.properties,sonar.host.url is configured to run as mentioned below.

sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 and now we want to change it to sonar.host.url=https://localhost.

On the browser https://localhost works fine. However when I configure this url in sonar-scanner.properties and try to run the sonar analysis, it says url can not be reached. Could anyone give me some suggestions to fix this issue.

Regards,
Sharieff.

Comment: Does it do this for every call or just the POSTs?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a valid certificate to your website. Using localhost is not the best choice; you should use and configure a valid domain name (https:/mycompany.com for example). On the machine you use to analyse you must update the Java Runtime by registering the certificate associated with this name and maybe also other (root) certificates in the certificate chain. See [this](https://drissamri.be/blog/2017/02/22/java-keystore-keytool-essentials) blog for all the details. After executing these steps you should be able to upload the analysis to you SonarQube instance.

Comment: Hi Jeroen Heier,

I'm using a valid SSL certificate and also we have a valid domain name for the instance. Instead of dns name I mentioned localhost in the description.
Anyways, I will check the links provided and let you know if the issue is resolved.